# Where to find the data saved by Parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

where can we find the cache or folder where the `PFUser currentUser` is stored after a user has signed up? I tried `Preferences > Locations > ...click on DerivedData`, but I could not find it. Also, is it saved in the NSDocument directory on the device? I don't know how to check for these informations, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to ask the iOS developers in **Parse** to know this information. If they want you to know where it's stored. Then, what's the good to hide the implementation? Why don't they just show us the open source code? If you still want to find that out, you probably just need to try every possible means. Or do you have any other more specific problems?

Comment: I was just curious to know how it worked, I thought the stackoverflow forum would be read by the developers ;-)

Comment: @Paul I don't think they will tell you that. lol. And the DerivedData is not something you think of. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279141/what-can-i-safely-delete-in-my-library-developer-xcode-deriveddata-directory

Comment: Just print it out and you can see all the data about the PFUser. They implemented `description` method.

Comment: ok well, maybe if a developer comes by, and would be happy to add some details, it would be great. Otherwise, nevermind. ;-) Thanks for the answer Lucas

Comment: Hope I can help you anything on Parse. I just love this product. lol

Comment: @Paul Parse Devs no longer use SO as a forum for communicating with devs like us. They use the google groups [Located Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers), where they frequently respond to questions, specifically Hector, he is extremely active.

Comment: Sure @Paul np. I don't think this answer directly resolves your question. Parse caches queries and PFFiles but they don't save any user information to the device after they sign up, that would be a security risk on their behalf,  that's why they call the log in method in viewDidAppear so they can do checks and balances as soon as the view populates, buttt if there is a cached query of `PFUser currentUser` then it will act accordingly which there is, but it won't count against your API request limit. I would post your question on the google group for a more elaborate response from the team.

Answer (score 0):

The current `PFUser` is stored in the `Library/Private Documents/Parse/currentUser` file on the device.

[Where does Parse store user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895257/where-does-parse-store-user-session/26899436#26899436)